# Get the last ID of a data row inserted into a database table

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

I'm using ASP.net to add a record into a table:

```
        With SqlDataSource1
            .InsertParameters("Name").DefaultValue = fldName.Value
            .InsertParameters("Email").DefaultValue = Text1.Value
            .InsertParameters("tContent").DefaultValue = taLE.Value
            .Insert()
        End With
```

I now realize that I need to get the id (a Unique Identifier that Auto Increments by 1) of the record I just added.

Cheers!

Comment: Which database vendor are you using (SQL Server, MySQL, other)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

USE

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

[LAST_INSERT_ID() doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)

***NOTE***

`LAST_INSERT_ID` is connection specific so you don't have to worry about locks. When you call it after your `INSERT`, it will return the id inserted by this `INSERT` *even if another `INSERT` was committed in between*.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are using MySQL. If you had been using SQL Server, I would suggest using:

```
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

There are other options, but they all have their reasons for being used:
[SQL SERVER – @@IDENTITY vs SCOPE_IDENTITY() vs IDENT_CURRENT – Retrieve Last Inserted Identity](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/)